# HTML agility pack get all divs with class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scape a complicated HTMl. I need to get some text from div's with certain class.

What I am trying to do is have the html agility pack to go over the whole html and find all divs whos class contains "listevent" and return me those.

When I searched online I found out that If I map it , it is possible, but some of these divs are under somemany divs so trying to find some easy way.

The HTML looks like this

```
<div>
    <div>
       <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="thisone listevent"></td>
            <td>
              <div class="thisone listevent"></td>
           </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can do it without HTMLAgility pack using index of your string. If you show your html you are trying to parse, this will help others to better answer you question.

Comment: Please provide the HTML or the link to help you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `SelectNodes` method

```
foreach(HtmlNode div in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'listevent')]"))
{
}
```

If you are more familiar with css style selectors, try [fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) and do this

```
document.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("div.listevent");
```

Comment: I tried but it returns null. Unless I map excatly where are the divs( I mean like SelecNodes("//div/div/td/...") it turns all null

Comment: Sorry , apparently I was having problem when loading the html.